# My SQL syntax is error, how to solve it?

Tags: mysql

This is the SQL syntax:

```
WITH max_budget(value) AS (SELECTMAX(budget) FROM department)
SELECT budget       
FROM department, max_budget
WHERE department.budget = max_budget.value;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'max_budget(value) AS (SELECTMAX(budget) FROM department)SELECT budget FROM ' at line 1
```

How can i solve this problem?, help me guys, thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It

Comment: This would have worked just fine in Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

[MySQL doesn't support Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql) so either your `mysql` tag is incorrect or you've pulled this syntax from nowhere.

To make this work with MySQL, you'll need to rewrite it as [derived tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/552c5/1). Note, these sql fiddles use the question that was a [duplicate of this](https://serverfault.com/questions/718895/i-have-complicated-sql-syntax-and-its-error-how-to-solve-it) as it was at least more interesting to answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql

This is the [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6470c/1) version but I guarantee whatever logic you're attempting could be simplified if you explained what you were attempting to do versus "code doesn't work"

This specific question suffers from two issues: The first and already addressed is that CTEs `WITH` don't exist in mysql.

The second is simply syntax. You have `SELECTMAX` instead of `SELECT MAX`

```
WITH max_budget(value) AS (SELECT MAX(budget) FROM department)
SELECT budget       
FROM department, max_budget
WHERE department.budget = max_budget.value;
```

The above is valid syntax for SQL Server and all DBMS that have implemented CTEs. The MySQL equivalent follows

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    department
WHERE
    department.budget =
    (
        SELECT MAX(budget) FROM department
    );
```

This uses a correlated subquery which has the distinct advantage of working in [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/348e1/1), [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33619/1), [PostGres](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/72f40/1), etc.

You could also write it as a derived table:

```
SELECT
    department.*
FROM
    department 
  JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(budget) AS value FROM department
    )  max_budget
  ON 
    department.budget = max_budget.value ;
```